# UISplitViewController in ViewBased application?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

How to add UISplitViewController in UIViewBased application?

Is is possible ?

I have started UIViewBased application project for my iPad app. I want to show SplitView on one button click. How can I implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple human interface guidelines forbid this and say that the UISplitViewController must be installed as the Root View Controller so it would be best to redesign your app with this in mind.